# Regex multiple matches concatenated

Tags: java

I have a string like this **"@@VV 1 ?? 28 > ##@@VV 3 78 ?? > ##@@VV ?? 5 27 > ##"** and I wants extract with a regex the three groups identifyed by this pattern **"@@VV .*>.*##"**. 
But if I compile my test string with previous pattern syntax I extract whole test string as a group and not three groups.
How can I define the regex string and get three groups?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String INPUT = "@@VV 1 ?? 28 > ##@@VV 3 78 ?? > ##@@VV ?? 5 27 > ##";
  String startChars = "@@";
  String sepChars = ">";
  String endChars = "##";
  String REGEX = startChars+"VV .*"+sepChars+".*"+endChars;
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);

  // get a matcher object
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(INPUT);
 //Prints the number of capturing groups in this matcher's pattern. 
  System.out.println("Group Count: "+matcher.groupCount());
  while(matcher.find()) {

     System.out.println(matcher.group());
  }      
}

Expected results:
Group Count: 3
@@VV 1 ?? 28 > ##
@@VV 3 78 ?? > ##
@@VV ?? 5 27 > ##

Actual results:
Group Count: 0
@@VV 1 ?? 28 > ##@@VV 3 78 ?? > ##@@VV ?? 5 27 > ##
```

Comment: How about  `Spring#split` ??

Answer (score 2):

Try to use "lazy" operators

```
startChars+"VV .*?"+sepChars+".*?"+endChars
```

notice `.*?`

Here is working example. https://www.regextester.com/?fam=108741

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing the capturing group: Enclosed by parenthesis.

The regex: `(@@VV.*?> ##)`